# Model validation error for checkbox value set using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core

In my view I have the following checkbox I also ave a search and a clear button which clears the control and resubmits the form to get the initial state. The field isFruit is a boolean non null field:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="IsFruit"></label> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input asp-for="IsFruit" type='checkbox' />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" title="Search results">Search</button>
<button id="btnClear" type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" title="Clear search values">Clear Search</button>
```

My script : I am clearing the checkbox and then submitting the form.

```
$("#btnClear").on("click", function () {
        $("input").val("");            
        $("#IsFruit").attr('checked', false);
        $("#frmSearch").submit();
    });
```

While the submit button works fine, the Clear button is throwing a validation error for the check box field saying "" is not a valid value even though I am setting the value for the check box. how do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

```
$('input').val("");
```

try

```
$('input:not([type="checkbox"])').val("");
```